# How to write and read nested list in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to write following list (nested list with its second element as an array) into an Excel spreadsheet cell using Python:

```
segData=([0, [250. , 251. , 251.6, 252. , 252.2, 252.4, 253. , 253.4, 253.6,
          253.8, 254.2, 254.6, 255.2, 256. , 256.8, 257.4, 257.8, 257.8,
          257.6, 257.4, 257.2, 257.2, 257.4, 257.6, 257.8, 258. , 258.2,
          258.4, 258.8], 0, 'active index.xlsm')
```

I have tried using the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(segData)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Segmented Data', index=False)
writer.save()
```

The list is successfully exported to excel, however, when I read the data from the excel again using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name='Segmented Data')
data=data.to_numpy()
```

The second column is interpreted as a string and does not like an array, as I cannot index it again.

So to summarize the issue is that I intend to write an array nested in a list to an excel sheet and then again read the data as an array.

Comment: What do you expect the excel document to look like?

Comment: I'm not even sure if Excel supports that. Wouldn't it always flatten it by default?

Comment: Ask yourself, - How does 'array' originally look in the excel cell?

Comment: @NoobVB It actually looks like a single entity, similar to string. What can be a correct approach then to write it in excel?